# AngularJS - Create HTML dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new with AngularJS and want to achieve the following task:

I load a specific id (integer number) from a server via an AJAX call.
Now I want to include the number in a HTML document. Now at the moment I do it like this:

```
identifier = getNumberFromServerViaAjax();
var app = angular.module("processFormApp", []);
    app.directive('ngProcessform', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div id="identifier">'+identifier+'</div>';
        }
    });
```

The above code is in an external JavaScript file.
So is this the right approach to insert data dynamically in a html-file? I also read something about $compile but this seems very complicated to me.

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial? This one is good to start: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial I think you need to understand angular basics

Comment: Actually the best way is to have a controller. Do the $http call in the controller. In the .success() function handle the value and store it into a $scope variable. Then in the HTML displaying it like this {{myvalue}}. You should do some great tutorial about angular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4&list=PL173F1A311439C05D&context=C48ac877ADvjVQa1PpcFONnl4Q5x8hqvT6tRBTE-m0-Ym47jO3PEE%3D

Comment: why don't you just use two way binding ?? i'm sorry i might not be understanding ur problem statement.

Comment: Well, the above code is already in a separate controller file. Maybe I need some additional knowledge about AngularJS, thanks for your help!